# Shortest Remaining Time - average turnaround time

Tags: algorithm, optimization, scheduling

Assuming all processes arrive at the same time, shortest job first seems to be optimal in terms of lowering the average turn around time. I also managed to prove that.

However, when procesess arrive at different times I felt like the optimal algorithm would be the Shortest Remaing Time (preemptive shortest job first). But I can't find a way to prove it. Can someone help me/point me to a solution? Or am I flat out wrong?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_remaining_time

You can run one process at a time. No context switch time.

EDIT:
Say we have n proccesses.

Each process has an execution time of P(i). 1<= i <= n

Each process becomes available for execution at a specific time R(i)

Each process ends running at some time C(i) (turn-around time) based on when it started running, if it was suspended e.t.c

all times are integers. no specific example. I just have to find an algorithm that optimizes the average turn around time ((C(1)+C(2)+...+C(n))/n) for any given input. (as low aas possible)

Comment: Provide some more context, please.

Comment: That helps, but please edit again to clarify these things: Are the P(i) given? Are the C(i) to be determined? "Preemptive" suggests that a job ( = "process"?) can be suspended and restarted again later, is that correct?  (If so, is there any penalty?  IOW, what exactly does "preemptive shortest job first" mean?)  Are the P(i) integer?  Is there just 1 machine?

Comment: yes job/process can be suspended in order to start running another process